# Is this way valid about vertical asymptotes?

Tags: calculus

I am used to employing Maple in teaching Calculus. Today, I asked a student to think of finding the vertical asymptote(s) of a function for example, $y=\frac{x+1}{x^2-25}$ by Maple. I wanted her to work with the denominator in someway, but she solve the equation respect to $x$ and then apply the definition of horizontal asymptote for $y^{-1}$.

It looked interesting, but may I ask if this way is legal in calculus for finding vertical asymptote of a function? I want to be sure of this way. Of course, I think there are some certain conditions for a function in this question, like existing $y^{-1}$. Thanks for your any ides.

Comment: You have a very creative student! ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since
$$
y=f(x) \Leftrightarrow x=f^{-1}(y),
$$
the graph of $f^{-1}$ is the graph of $f$ rotated so that the $x$-axis becomes the $y$-axis. Hence a horizontal asymptote for $f^{-1}$ becomes a vertical asymptote for $f$, and viceversa.

It is a nice approach, indeed. Of course it requires the invertibility of $f$, at least locally. But it is an interesting intuition for a student.

Comment: Thanks so much for making me sure. :)